# how to add a drop down list to a <span> using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

html part:

```
<body onload="init();firstInit();">
```

script part:

```
function init(){
var tb = new Ext.Toolbar({
renderTo: 'toolbar',
height: 25
});             
var ht='<table><tr>';
ht+='<td>';
ht+='<div class="font">Mode : </div>';
ht+='</td>';
ht+='<td id="visumode.container">';
ht+='<select id="visuMode.select" size="1" onchange="fRefresh();">';
ht+='<option value="Direct">Direct</option>';               
ht+='</select>';
ht+='</td>';
ht+='</tr></table>';
span = document.createElement("span");
span.innerHTML=  ht;
tb.addElement(span);
}
function firstInit(){
var d document.getElementById("visumode.container");
alert(d)
}
```

this is a small part of the code, in the html part the result are put in a form.
the alert is null why?

Comment: First off, i wouldn't add a select element (block element) to a span element (inline element), why not just add it to a div. You also don't do anything with the resulting span element, add it to a container or return it from the function and then add it to your DOM.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply i will edit my question with the real code.

Comment: @BasTuijnman Select is not a block level element. So, putting it in a span is not wrong. Just depends where the span is supposed to be inserted.

Comment: @René You're right, it is indeed not a block element, still dont like the semantics though :)

Comment: In your updated code(really annoying that you updated your question with so much...) `var d document...` should be `var d = document...`. Next time mark an answer as accepted and create a new question instead of changing your entire question.

Comment: i didn't want at first to put a lot of codes.. there is an equal in my code.

Comment: Yes, some part is equal but the already given correct answers make no sense anymore because of your updated code. Also, try to avoid writing html strings inside JavaScript. Write the html inside... well, html. And just update nodes, elements and values.

Comment: oh lol. Now I noticed you mean there is an aqual sign in your code. Well, I don't see it. And my point is still valid ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have closing tag: `</select>` for `ht`, and the `span` variable is not added to the DOM.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply i will edit my question with the real code.

Answer (score 2):

You create a `span` element, but then you don't do anything with it.

You'll need to add `span` to the document, somewhere:

```
<div id="myContainer"></div>
```

```
document.getElementById('myContainer').appendChild(span);
```

You'll also want to add a closing tag to your select:

```
ht += '</select>';
```

Comment: thank you for your fast reply i will edit my question with the real code.